# SDN 4 query by property list with depth 1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I need a Spring Data Neo4J repository method which takes as input a list of names and returns all nodes with a specific label which have one of those names, with depth 1.

For example:

```
Set<Person> findAllByName(Set<String> names)
```

should return a Set containing all Persons whose names are in the "names" Set including all their immediate children nodes.

I am open to writing custom queries, filters or anything else, I just want to get this to work somehow.

I already tried writing a custom repository implementation using Neo4jOperations.loadAllByProperties, but I cannot figure out how to create a filter which matches against a list.

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cypher query like the following in your repository:

```
@Query( "MATCH (a:Person) "+
        "WHERE a.personId IN {0} " +
        "RETURN a ")
List<Person> getPersonList(Set<String> personSet);
```

Then just call the repository query in your controller:

```
List<Person> listPerson = personRepository.getPersonList(names);
```

**EDIT**: since you want the relationships of Person to also be populated, something like the following could work, based on [this](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) blog entry:

```
@Query( "MATCH (a:Person) "+
        "WHERE a.personId IN {0} "+
        "WITH a "+
        "MATCH p=(a)-[r*0..1]-()"+
        "RETURN a, nodes(p), rels(p)")
List<Person> getPersonList(Set<String> personSet);
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the depth part. I need the Persons in the response to have all the relationships populated (depth 1)

Comment: That's correct. Based on the `Map all related entities` section of [this](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) blog post perhaps my edit would work. Unfortunately, I can't test it myself at the moment.